# How to scale the image size in a sprite

Tags: css

I have a sprite with all 32 x 32 images and I am using them in my project but in some places, I want the image to be 64 x 50 instead of 32 x 32. Now, how can I do that using CSS. Is there any way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be any different from handling any other size? Just find out which point in the image you need to have be the origin, position the image there, and set the dimensions to whatever the sprite dimensions are. Or are you saying you actually want to scale the sprite, i.e. distort it?

Comment: first of all, you are doing it wrong. you want different images for different sizes or else have a single SVG file. stretching the same image is an ugly fix, IMO.

Comment: I have around 40 32 x 32 svg images. Hence I added them into a sprite. In one place, I am making 3 images into a different dimension like above. The clarity looks good though. I just used the scale() property suggested by ShellZero and it worked awesome.

Comment: @Marley if those images are of svg format, you don't need scale just change the dimensions. it should work.

Comment: I can't just change the dimensions of an image inside the sprite because the whole sprite itself is a huge image with all the 40 images one by one stacked up! If I give dimensions, the image doesn't change in size at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use `transform: scale()` property to scale your image inside the sprite or you can use the new `zoom` property of css.

For example: If you have the image 32 x 32 and want to scale it to lets say 64 x 64. Simple multiply by 2 should do the trick. So, you would use something as follows:

`transform: scale(2.0);` `// multiplies both coordinates and you will get your scaled image of 64 x 64.`

or you can simply do `zoom: 2;`

Now, in your case as you want to x axis in different way and y axis in different way implying x as width and y as height. You could do as following:

```
transform: scaleX(2.0);
transform: scaleY(1.5625);
```

That should do the trick :)

And one more thing, the zoom property is not yet supported by Firefox which is really weird but scale is supported by all the browsers.

Support:
 
[CSS Zoom](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom)
[Scale](http://caniuse.com/#search=scale)

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShellZero it worked great. this is what I have been looking for. I loved the zoom property but scale is much more flexible. I liked it. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it helped you out. Please mark my post as the answer if you are satisfied by my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `background-position` and `background-size` property for that.

In this example the original image is 50X50, set as background to 100X100 and 100X75 (stretched):

```css
#a1 {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
#a2 {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff);
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: 100px 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a1"></div>
<br />
<div id="a2"></div>
```